# wpf textblock exact top margin with px

Tags: c#, wpf, margin, textblock

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ctTbMain" Text="INITIALIZING THE SYSTEM NEW UI"     Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="190px" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ctPagebody}" Style="{StaticResource styleTextInit1}" />
```

Lets say that I want to set this TextBox with exact 290px from the top margin
How should I do that?

Comment: Please provide more details. If its regarding only placing control to 290px from top. Try Canvas.Top="290". It will consider windows height and width.

Comment: use a converter and convert pixel value to double

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a 290px margin, just set the margin.

```
<TextBlock 
  x:Name="ctTbMain" 
  Text="INITIALIZING THE SYSTEM NEW UI" 
  Margin="0,290,0,0" 
  Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ctPagebody}" 
  Style="{StaticResource styleTextInit1}"
/>
```